# Which type can I use for a MediaStream in a Vue prop?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I set up a mediastream (multi WebRTC) and will put each `MediaStream` into a the child component which has a video tag included. The type of the stream is `MediaStream` but there is no matching type for a vue prop. [Vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Type-Checks)

That is my code:

```js
props: {
  stream: { default: null, type: MediaStream }
}
```

The type `MediaStream` does not exist and throws an error. But which type is right one here?

Comment: Where do you see the error? It's possibly just your linter complaining in which case, you could just add an ignore rule

Comment: Works fine over here (I added a `MediaStream` prop to the `HelloWorld.vue` component) ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-wiles-wl8bk

Comment: @Phil thanks for your response. I receive the error on the page `ReferenceError MediaStream is not defined`
`Module../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./components/stream/videoItem.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&@22:`

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution but it works: `stream: undefined`.